# make target depends on execution

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want my make target to be dependent on execution file. For example I have simple makefile:

```
a.out: test.cpp
    gcc test.cpp
```

I want something like that:

```
a.out: test.cpp, `which gcc`
    gcc test.cpp
```

It means that changing your gcc (in particular updating) will lead rebuilding of a.out (even if test.cpp wasn't changed).

But it looks like unshapely solution, because you should add one more prerequisite for each rule each used in this rule tool.

Is there other solutions of this problem?

Comment: The solution is that you usually *know* when you change of `gcc` version. This is not a change that is done regularly, it is rather seldom during development. Therefore, as the user know that `gcc` changes, he/she can issue a `make clean` command to rebuild everything on next `make`.

Comment: Also, note that the recompilation would only fire if the GCC you'r currently using had been modified since the program was last built, not simply because it was a different program from what you used last time.

Comment: Thank you! I certainly understand it and it is really what I want.

Answer (score 1):

In a GNU `make` makefile, you could use:

```
CC := $(shell which gcc)

a.out: test.cpp ${CC}
    ${CC} -o $@ test.cpp
```

Note that the build would only trigger if the compiler executable was modified, not simply because it was different from last time the program was built.  Historically, SUN `make` had a '.make.state' file and a `.KEEP_STATE` target which kept track of such things. IBM Rational ClearCase has a `clearmake` that also tracks such issues if you choose to make it do so.